# How to skip “Welcome Page” in Chrome using adb

Tags: adb, chrome-for-android

I am trying to open a URL in Google Chrome using adb command line. Have set "--no-first-run" using following command -

```
adb shell 'echo "chrome --no-first-run" > /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line'
```

Have taken the command line switch from the following website - http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Then I execute the following commands,

```
adb -s TA99300UFC shell am set-debug-app com.android.chrome
adb -s TA99300UFC shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d 'http://wikipedia.org'
```

Still the "Welcome Page" shows up.

How can I skip this and go directly to the website URL passed in command?

Comment: Weird! I didn't need `--no-first-run` trick and `am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d 'http://wikipedia.org'` is working here perfectly for Chrome v46.0. See if changing the component name works. Replace `com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main` with `org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity` or use `""` instead of `''`. Tell us the results. Use `--activity-clear-task` at the end, if necessary.

Comment: Related: [Open a new tab in chrome from a shortcut or app](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/123662) / Which Android version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved after the `--persistent` flag was added in the `set-debug-app` command.

So the command changed to `adb -s TA99300UFC shell am set-debug-app --persistent com.android.chrome`. After that `chrome://version` displayed `chrome --display-fre` under the `Command line` section.