# Opening incognito tab in chrome when swiping on chrome icon?

Tags: chrome-for-android, nova-launcher

As you all know that Nova Launcher allows assigning swipe actions to icons on home screen. For example I have attached the swipe action on the dialer to call home directly.

Now I am trying to assign the activity to chrome so that when I swipe the chrome icon it opens the chrome in incognito mode. 
I have tried assigning the activities from chrome but it does not have separate incognito function.

So I was wondering to any of you guys know anything of this sort can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/3j1ukt/help_open_chrome_incognito_tab_probably_using/) Reddit post it is not possible when writing an app as the Chrome code ignores the request if it is not Chrome initiating it, so an app or user cannot trigger the incognito tab. I assume the same applies when trying to launch the activity 'manually'.

> So what these are doing, is checking whether the intent should be ignored based on whether it is the user or chrome performing the action. They make this determination based on whether there is a token from a signed Google app. So unless there is a way to trick find that token and figure out how to attach it to Tasker I don't think it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it by going into swipe action: then to the shortcuts tab: Activities at the top of the list: scroll all the way to find chrome: and tap on (com.google.android.apps.chrome.main)