# Open Chrome URL home screen shortcut in incognito mode

Tags: chrome-for-android, tasker, home-screen-shortcuts, private-mode

I have a shortcut to a Google Form on my home screen. For a couple of reasons I would like for it to open in incognito mode (to prevent the option of editing the form, and so that once the Chrome app is closed the tab will not still be there the next time I open Chrome), however there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to achieve this.

I do also have Tasker but I'm completely unfamiliar with it's capabilities, so if it can help in any way that's fine.

Comment: An alternative way would be to install a different web browser like Firefox, Opera, ... and create the link using this browser where you are not logged in.

Comment: Not looking positive. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/148326/96277

Comment: Disappointing but not the end of the world. I've taken the suggestion of @Robert and just installed a different browser, and configured it to close tabs on exit.